# Different @QuarkusTestResource per Quarkus profile

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, quarkus

I have just set up my project to use `H2DatabaseTestResource` in the tests.
I also have created a custom `PostgresDatabaseTestResource`, following [this brilliant blog](https://www.morling.dev/blog/quarkus-and-testcontainers/)

If I manually change the `***DatabaseTestResource` written in the `@QuarkusTestResource` annotation, they both work separately.

What I want to achieve now is to use one resource or the other based on a Quarkus profile or something similar, but I could not find a way to do this.

Any idea?

Comment: You mean that you want to have one `QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager` apply to one `QuarkusTestProfile` and another applying to second test profile?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I want to achieve!

Answer (score 2):

`QuarkusTestProfile` has the `testResources` method that you can use for this case. See https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/2.9.0.CR1/integration-tests/spring-web/src/test/java/io/quarkus/it/spring/web/testprofile/Profiles.java#L35 for an example usage.